Not all the sides of the 3D cube display
I'm trying to create a 3D cube using CSS but not all sides of the cube appear as they should
the left , right and top sides of my cube doesn't display at all
only the front , bottom and backward of the 3D cube.
I tried to change the size of the cube, and I tried to change the transform properties and to play with the angles however it didn't work
any help would be amazing.
here is my CSS code, I'm sorry for its length


.container {
  width: 400px;
  height: 400px;
  border: 2px solid white;
  border-radius: 4px;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
  perspective: 800px;
  perspective-origin: top right;
}
.cube {
    position: relative;
    width: 200px;
    height: 200px;
    transform-style: preserve-3d;
    border: 2px solid white;
    animation: cubeRotate 5s linear infinite;
}
.face {
    position: absolute;
    width: 200px;
    height: 200px;
    opacity: 0.9;
    line-height: 100px;
    text-align: center;
    font-size: 1.4rem;
}
.front {
    background-color: lightblue;
    transform: translateZ(100px);
}
.backward {
    background-color: lightgreen;
    transform: translateZ(-100px);
}
.left {
    background-color: peru;
    transform: rotateY('-90deg') translateZ(-100px);
}
.right {
    background-color: blueviolet;
    transform: rotateY('90deg') translateZ(100px) ;
}
.top {
    background-color: brown;
    transform: rotateX('90deg') translateZ(100px);
}
.bottom {
    background-color: aqua;
    transform: translateZ(100px) rotateX('-90deg');
}
@keyframes cubeRotate {
  from {
    transform: rotateY(0deg) 
}
  to { 
    transform: rotateY(360deg) 
}
}
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css">
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>Document</title>
</head>
<body>
    <div class="container">
        <div class="cube">
            <div class="face front">Front </div>
                <div class="face left">Left  </div>
                    <div class="face right">Right </div>
                        <div class="face backward">Backward</div>
                        <div class="face top">Top</div>
                        <div class="face bottom">Bottom</div>
        </div>
    </div>
</body>
</html>




Please show the relevant HTML and make the code into a runnable snippet (use <> in the editor).

Thanks for the snippet. Have a really close look at where each of the sides is positioned.

OK thank you very much

Don't use apostrophes around the deg values - note how bottom isn't actually rotated around x axis. Do you use your browser devtools inspect facility to see exactly what CSS is being applied? It will also show you what are invalid values.

What I understood from the sides is that for top and bottom maybe needs to be translateY because Y axis is for up and down? I think...

Yes, you'll need to move them up or down.

thank you the problem was the apostrophes now all the sides are showing correctly except the bottom

yes!! I figure it out thank you for your help. How can I give you a rate on your comment? (sorry I am new here)

for the .bottom you used first translate and then rotate. Do the opposite. First rotate and then use translate like in all the other classes.

No need to rate a comment! Glad it's sorted for you.

Also, you have issues with your rotation, for some panes/faces, If you use i.e: backface-visibility: hidden; you'll understand which are the ones in conflict. PS- my suggestion anyways would be to first use translate and then rotate. Also, .backward is better called just .back


don't use quotes in rotate function rotateY('-90deg') use rotateY(-90deg)
instead of first using rotate and then translate (or worse, mix the two logics),   first: translate a face, and then rotate it:



.container {
  width: 400px;
  height: 400px;
  border: 2px solid white;
  border-radius: 4px;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
  perspective: 800px;
}

.cube {
  position: relative;
  width: 200px;
  height: 200px;
  transform-style: preserve-3d;
  animation: cubeRotate 5s linear infinite alternate;
}

.face {
  position: absolute;
  width: 200px;
  height: 200px;
  opacity: 0.7;
  line-height: 100px;
  text-align: center;
  font-size: 1.4rem;
  /* backface-visibility: hidden; /* uncomment to test all 6 faces */
}

.front {
  background-color: lightblue;
  transform: translateZ(100px) rotateY(0deg);
}

.back {
  background-color: lightgreen;
  transform: translateZ(-100px) rotateY(180deg);
}

.left {
  background-color: peru;
  transform: translateX(-100px) rotateY(-90deg);
}

.right {
  background-color: blueviolet;
  transform: translateX(100px) rotateY(90deg);
}

.top {
  background-color: brown;
  transform: translateY(-100px) rotateX(90deg);
}

.bottom {
  background-color: aqua;
  transform: translateY(100px) rotateX(-90deg);
}

@keyframes cubeRotate {
  from {
    transform: rotateY(0deg);
  }
  to {
    transform: rotateY(360deg);
  }
}
<div class="container">
  <div class="cube">
    <div class="face front">Front</div>
    <div class="face left">Left </div>
    <div class="face right">Right </div>
    <div class="face back">Back</div>
    <div class="face top">Top</div>
    <div class="face bottom">Bottom</div>
  </div>
</div>



The above can now be rewritten also using translate and rotate CSS properties without changing the values for axis:


.container,
.cube,
.face {
  position: relative;
  display: grid;
  place-items: center;
  width: var(--size, 200px);
  aspect-ratio: 1;
  transform-style: preserve-3d;
}

.container {
  --size: 400px;
  perspective: 800px;
}

.cube {
  --size: 200px;
  animation: cubeRotate 5s linear infinite;
}

.face {
  position: absolute;
  opacity: 0.8;
  font-size: 1.4rem;
  background-color: var(--bg);
}

.front {
  --bg: #0bf;
  translate: 0 0 100px; rotate: 0 0 0 90deg;
}

.back {
  --bg:#fb0;
  translate: 0 0 -100px; rotate: 0 1 0 180deg;
}

.left {
  --bg:#f0b;
  translate: -100px 0 0; rotate: 0 1 0 -90deg;
}

.right {
  --bg:#0fb;
  translate: 100px 0 0; rotate: 0 1 0 90deg;
}

.top {
  --bg:#b0f;
  translate: 0 -100px 0; rotate: 1 0 0 90deg;
}

.bottom {
  --bg:#bf0;
  translate: 0 100px 0; rotate: 1 0 0 -90deg;
}

@keyframes cubeRotate {
  to { rotate: 1 1 1 1turn; }
}
<div class="container">
  <div class="cube">
    <div class="face front">Front</div>
    <div class="face left">Left </div>
    <div class="face right">Right </div>
    <div class="face back">Back</div>
    <div class="face top">Top</div>
    <div class="face bottom">Bottom</div>
  </div>
</div>



